# Остановка работы потока по нажатию кнопки

Tags: c#, winforms, многопоточность

Я создал приложение для перепрошивки устройства по интерфейсу UART[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хочу добавить необязательное, но желаемое взаимодействие с программой:
Остановка работы потока по нажатию на *кнопку "Остановить выполнение"*.
Программа работает следующим образом:

```
private void Execute_Commands_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        // Нажатие на кнопку "Выполнить команды"
        {
            // Очистить данные
            Clear_Data();
            // Если нет ошибок в полях
            if (Check_All_Fields())
            {
                // Если есть соединение с портом
                if (Check_Port())
                {
                    // Если параметры работы с портом установлены успешно
                    if (Set_Port_Settings())
                    {
                        // Обновить данные Hex- файла
                        Refresh_Hex_File_Data();
                        // Если устройство не синхронизировано
                        if (!Is_Synchronised)
                        {
                            // Поток для синхронизации
                            Thread Sync_Thread;
                            // Поток для синхронизации
                            Sync_Thread = new Thread(delegate()
                            {
                                // Выключить элементы управления
                                Set_Enable(false);
                                // Попытаться синхронизировать
                                Try_To_Synchronise_Device(Convert.ToInt32(
                                This_Common.Read_From_Registry(This_Common.Key_Sync_Attempts)));
                                // Включить элементы управления
                                Set_Enable(true);
                            });
                            // Записываем поток как текущий
                            Active_Thread = Sync_Thread;
                            // Запуск потока
                            Sync_Thread.Start();
                            // Ожидание завершения работы потока
                            Sync_Thread.Join();
                        }
                        // Если устройство синхронизировано
                        if (Is_Synchronised)
                        {
                            // Обновить список команд
                            Refresh_Commands();
                            // Попытаться послать команды на порт
                            Try_To_Send_Commands();
                        }
                        // Если устройство не синхронизировано
                        else
                        {
                            // Вывести ошибку
                            This_Common.Show_Error_Message("Не удалось синхронизироваться с устройством!");
                        }
                        // Закрыть порт
                        Selected_Port.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

В функции `void Set_Enable(bool)` Все элементы управления становятся неактивными и включается только *кнопка "Остановить выполнение"*.
при нажатии на эту кнопку активный поток закрывается: `Active_Thread.Abort()`.

Проблема заключается в следующем: после ожидания выполнения группы методов в отдельном потоке я теряю возможность обрабатывать нажатия на *кнопку "Остановить выполнение"*. Как это можно исправить?

Вариант с Task не сработал. Код следующий:

```
// Обработчик запроса отмены задачи
CancellationTokenSource Source = new CancellationTokenSource();
// Переменная отключения выполнения задачи
CancellationToken Cancel_Token;
// Задача "Синхронизировать"
Task Sync_Task;
// Задать задачу
Sync_Task = new Task(delegate()
{   
// Попытаться синхронизироваться
Try_To_Synchronise_Device(Convert.ToInt32(This_Common.Read_From_Registry(This_Common.Key_Sync_Attempts)));
}, Cancel_Token);
// Запуск задачи
Sync_Task.Start();
// Ожидаем выполнение задачи
Source.Wait();
```

При клике на *кнопку "Остановить выполнение"*: `Source.Cancel();`

Comment: А почему вы пользуйтесь `Thread`, а не `Task`? В таске можно задать токен отмены и когда надо отменить задачу, можно выбросить исключение.

Comment: Потому что с потоками работаю впервые и не знаю, как лучше. Попробовал я сделать через Task. Результат тот же: блок формы на время выполнения задачи

Comment: Покажите код, который работает с использованием `Task`, вы токен отмены использовали?

Comment: `Sync_Thread.Join();` - вот это блокирует вашу форму. Вы можете переделать тред на таск и асинхронно ждать, когда таск закончит свою работу

Comment: @Bulson, я добавил код с Task в вопрос

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Я тоже наклепал пример попроще.

[image: Пример работы]

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    //источник токена отмены
    CancellationTokenSource _tokenSource;

    //Запуск
    private async void _buttonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //через него будем оповещать о ходе выполнения задачи
        Progress<string> progess = new Progress<string>(text => this._labelOutput.Text = text);

        //готовим токен отмены
        _tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        CancellationToken cancelToken = _tokenSource.Token;

        //запускаем долгую задачу
        try
        {
            this._labelOutput.Text = "Начинаем...";
            //обратите внимание на передачу токена отмены, и экземпл. прогресса
            this._labelOutput.Text = await Task.Run(() => DoSomething(cancelToken, progess), cancelToken);
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            this._labelOutput.Text = "Задача отменена.";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            this._labelOutput.Text = $"В задаче произошла ошибка: {ex.Message}";
        }
    }


    //Отмена
    private void _buttonCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _tokenSource.Cancel();
    }

    //Эта самая долгая задача, обратите внимание на тип параметра progess он IProgress<T>
    private string DoSomething(CancellationToken cancelToken, IProgress<string> progess)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            //сообщаем о прогрессе
            progess.Report($"Этап: {i}");

            //задержка между этапами 1 сек.
            cancelToken.WaitHandle.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

            //здесь будет выброшено исключение в случае нажатия на кнопку отмены
            cancelToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested(); 
       }

        return "Готово!";
    }
}
```

Comment: В чем преимущество `Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500)).Wait();` перед простым `Thread.Sleep(500)` ?

Comment: @tym32167 `Thread.Sleep(500)` , на сколько я помню, "вышибает" задачу из контекста переключения, а `Task.Delay()` - это именно задержка. Хотя я могу и ошибаться.

Comment: `Task.Delay()` это задержка, которая создаст внутри себя таймер и отправит его в пул, а `Wait` выполнит после ещё кучу операций. Я потому и не понял, чем `Task.Delay.Wait` будет лучше - это задержка, которая также блочит поток, только операций больше делает и механизмы другие использует.

Comment: Сейчас попробую сделать так

Comment: @Bulson, спасибо огромное! Очень помогли)

Comment: @GeorgeTuzikov всегда, пожалуйста.

Comment: @tym32167, ОК, буду знать. Я использовал `Task.Delay()` только исходя из единственности применяемого инструмента.

Comment: @Bulson в таком случае вам следует сделать `DoSomething` асинхронным, и использовать `await Task.Delay(...)`. Кстати, у `Task.Delay` есть перегрузка которая принимает токен отмены - было бы логично использовать именно ее.

Comment: @Bulson в синхронном же коде с той же целью можно использовать `cancelToken.WaitHandle.WaitOne(...)`

Comment: @PavelMayorov, большое спасибо, за ценные замечания, буду иметь в виду.

Comment: @Bulson будете иметь в виду ... но код не исправите?

Comment: @PavelMayorov сейчас исправлю...

Comment: @Bulson да, еще замечание. ToString в форматированных строках вызывать не надо, оно само его вызовет.

Comment: @PavelMayorov я исправил, так нормально?

Comment: @Bulson да, теперь нормально

Answer (score 4):

В общем случае вы не можете *корректно* остановить произвольную программу снаружи принудительно (некорректно-то можно через TerminateThread сделать).

Остановка должна быть кооперативной. Это означает, что ваш поток должен периодически проверять не пытаются ли его остановить и если пытаются - то остановиться. Применительно к вашему коду это означает что вам нужно переписать метод `Try_To_Synchronise_Device` так, чтобы он поддерживал отмену и остановку.

В простейшей случае для остановки будет достаточно изменчивого булевого поля:

```
private volatile bool stop = false;

// ...

while (!stop)
{
    // что-то делаем
}
```

В более сложных случаях можно воспользоваться токенами отмены:

```
private CancellationTokenSource stop = new CancellationTokenSource();

// ...

while (!stop.IsCancellationRequested) 
{
    // что-то делаем
}
```

Но зачастую программа "висит" не в вашем коде, а в чужом, делая блокирующий внешний вызов. В таком случае для завершения потока нужно этот вызов как-то прервать. Это также нельзя сделать принудительно - только кооперативно, т.е. внешний код должен предусматривать прерывание долгих операций.

В простейшем случае внешний код просто принимает токен отмены и дальше делает все сам:

```
foo.Bar(baz, "Hello, world!", 42, stop.Token); // Вызов прервется при отмене токена
```

В более сложных случаях у внешнего кода будет какой-то метод который нужно вызвать для отмены. В таком случае вам пригодится метод Register:

```
var token = stop.Token;
using (token.Register(() => foo.Cancel()))
    foo.Bar(baz, "Hello, world!", 42);
```

Иногда внешний объект можно закрыть чтобы прервать все операции с ним:

```
var token = stop.Token;
using (token.Register(() => foo.Dispose()))
    foo.Bar(baz, "Hello, world!", 42);
```

Answer (score 2):

Наклепал пример, как работать с асинхронной операцией и как её отменять

```
public class MyWindow : Window
{
    Button btStart;
    Button btStop;
    TextBlock tb;
    CancellationTokenSource currentOperationTioken;
    Task currentOperation;

    public MyWindow()
    {
        // Тут просто создает контроды на форме и подписываем на нужные события
        this.Width = 450;
        this.Height = 200;
        this.WindowStartupLocation = System.Windows.WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;

        var mainPanel = new StackPanel() 
        { 
            Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal, 
            HorizontalAlignment= System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Stretch,
            VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Stretch,           
        };      

        btStart = new Button() { Content = "Start", Width=150 };
        btStop = new Button() {Content = "Stop", Width=150};
        btStop.IsEnabled = false;
        tb = new TextBlock() {Width=150};

        mainPanel.Children.Add(btStart);
        mainPanel.Children.Add(btStop);
        mainPanel.Children.Add(tb);

        this.AddChild(mainPanel);

        // подптсь на события
        btStart.Click+=StartClick;
        btStop.Click+=StopClick;
    }
```

асинхронный обработчик, тут мы запускаем нашу операцию и передаем ей токен для отмены, ждем конца операции и обновляем состояние кнопок.

```
    private async void StartClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
        btStart.IsEnabled = false;
        btStop.IsEnabled = true;
        tb.Text = string.Empty;

        currentOperationTioken = new CancellationTokenSource();
        currentOperation = Task.Run(() => HeavyWork(currentOperationTioken.Token));

        await currentOperation;

        btStart.IsEnabled = true;
        btStop.IsEnabled = false;
    }
```

В стопе просто вызываем отмену операции

```
    private void StopClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        currentOperationTioken.Cancel();        
    }
```

Наша долгая операция. Как только увидит сигнал об отмене - прекратит работу

```
    private void HeavyWork(CancellationToken token)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => tb.Text += $"{Environment.NewLine}{i} iteration");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            if (token.IsCancellationRequested) return;
        }
    }
}
```

Запустить окошко можно оч просто

```
void Main()
{
    new MyWindow().ShowDialog();
}
```

Результат

[image: Результат]

Comment: Вот с этим `if (token.IsCancellationRequested)` метод после отмены все равно будет иметь статус `Completed`, потому рекомендуют использовать выброс и отлов исключения `cancelToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();`.

Comment: @Bulson Если важно знать, как задача была завершена, то да. В моем примере это не важно :)