# Как создается многозадачность?

Tags: c#

Как создается многозадачность?

Например, программа скачивает картинки с сайта, на котором много категорий "Авто, мото, природа, и т.д.". Открывать сразу несколько копий программы не удобно, хочу сделать так, чтобы можно было добавлять задачу. Например выбрал категорию, путь к папке для сохранения картинок, нажал "Добавить" и, например в `listbox`, добавилась задача. И таких задач можно добавлять несколько. Запускать, останавливать и удалять ненужные. Я понимаю, что нужно создавать поток для каждой задачи, но не пойму как запоминать какой поток нужен, чтобы его запустить или остановить.

Например, нажал я в `listbox` на 3 задачу, далее нажимаю кнопку "Старт". Но как узнать какой поток нужен? Заносить их в массив? Есть ли другие реализации?

Comment: Смотрите в сторону `Task` и async/await.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/758663/222542