# C Sharp форма в другом потоке

Tags: c#, winforms, многопоточность

Есть программа. Выполняет объемные операции и виснет намертво. Хотелось бы сделать визуализацию работы.

Сделана форма с гифкой который я открываю в начале выполнения закрываю в конце.
Но открывающая форма виснет вместе с основной.

Как я понял её каким то образом нужно вызвать асинхронно.
Как это можно реализовать с передачей параметра в вызов и потом закрыть её из основной формы?

Comment: Подобных вашему вопросов здесь задано уже было много раз. Для асинхронной работы надо использовать `async/await` и `Task.Run()`. Вот пример: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/758663/222542

Answer (score 5):

Набросал базовый пример, как можно что то запустить параллельно с репортами. 
Сначала создает новое окно для прогресса, потом запускаем задачу. Task.Run отправит задачу в пул потоков. Как задача завершится, закрываем окно с прогрессом.

```
class MyForm : Form
{       
    public MyForm()
    {
        var b = new Button();
        b.Click+=RunTask;
        b.Text = "Click Me";    
        this.Controls.Add(b);
    }

    private async void RunTask(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var progress = new Progress<int>();
        var progressWindow = new Form();
        var progressBar = new ProgressBar();        

        progressWindow.Controls.Add(progressBar);           
        progress.ProgressChanged+= (s, v) => progressBar.Value = v;     

        progressWindow.Show();

        await Task.Run(() =>
        {           
            RunSomethingBig(progress);          
        });
        progressWindow.Close();                 
    }   

    private void RunSomethingBig(IProgress<int> progress)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i <= 100; i += 10)
        {
            progress.Report(i);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Эм. Тут как то наоборот выходит. По кнопке запускается метод который отображает прогресс выполнения и потом начинает выполнять какую то задачу. У меня уже идёт выполнение кода я добавил метод private async void showProgress(object sender, EventArgs e){} он конечно открыл окно но как теперь его закрыть? :-D

Comment: @Дмитрий Давайте определимся. Мой код работает как надо. Ваш очевидно нет (иначе не было бы вопроса). Тогда верным будет не подгонять мой код под ваш, а подгонять ваш код под мой. Меняйте свои условия, меняйте свой код, так, чтобы вам было удобно и прогресс показывать, и окна закрывать.