# Как правильно в C# убивать потоки?

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Здравствуйте! К примеру, у меня работает приложение. В нем запускается какое-то задание в отдельном потоке где делаются разные действия. И возникла ситуация, что мне нужно срочно остановить этот поток. Как это сделать наиболее безопасно и эффективно?

Слышал про Thread.Abort(), но правильно ли его использовать? Насколько знаю в Java резко убивать потоки нельзя.

Comment: Используйте [токен отмены операции](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken?view=netframework-4.7.1)

Comment: Вот тут я отвечал на похожий вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/758713/178779