# CancellationToken для чего?

Tags: c#

Объясните пожалуйста на пальцах, для чего эта штука `CancellationToken` существует и как ей пользоваться. Почему возник вопрос, подключил стороннюю библиотеку для работы с IMAP, там существует метод, который требует выше описанную штуку обязательным параметром, вот [мануал](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/M_MailKit_Net_Imap_ImapClient_Idle.htm).

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[CancellationToken](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) передается как параметр и используется для [оповещения кода о необходимости отмены операции](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads). То есть вы создаете токен, передаете его в сторонний код, но если вам надо этот сторонний код оповестить, что вы хотите отменить операцию, вы для этого используете этот токен. Пример есть по первой ссылке в MSDN или вот ещё [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/758650/179763)

Comment: Типо делегат отмены получается?

Comment: @Winteriscoming я не знаю, что вы имеете ввиду под делегатом отмены. Если это флаг, который показывает что операцию хотят отменить, то да )

Comment: Ну через эту штуку мы получается можем прервать операцию другого метода, правильно? Даже в одном потоке?

Comment: @Winteriscoming этой штукой мы можем _проинформировать_ другой метод о том, что нужно прерывание

Comment: @Winteriscoming нет, мы можем только оповестить другой метод, что мы хотим его прервать. А вот прервется он или нет - это уже ему решать.

Answer (score 4):

В качестве дополнения к правильному ответу @tym32167:

В .NET принята *кооперативная* отмена операций. То есть, вы должны передать внутрь операции информацию о том, что вам более не нужен её результат, а уж операция должна позаботиться о том, чтобы правильно оборвать себя.

Сама по себе отмена токена не вызывает обрыв операции. Обычно операция просматривает время от времени в удобных для этого точках выполнения, не требуется ли от неё отмена, и корректно завершает работу в случае необходимости. (Корректное завершение работы чаще всего выглядит снаружи как выброс исключения наподобие `OperationCanceledException`.)

Оборвать операцию автоматически снаружи, без сотрудничества со стороны самой операции, довольно сложно. Дело в том, что при окончании работы операции ей, возможно, придётся подчистить за собой: удалить временные файлы, отмапить разделяемую память, исключить себя от списка текущих операций, закрыть открытые окна. Внешний код никак не может знать, что именно нужно операции для корректного завершения. Поэтому он и не пытается оборвать операцию.

---

Известное исключение из этого правила — ASP.NET, который иногда убивает потоки по собственной инициативе.