# Остановка BackgroundWorker в бесконечном цикле

Tags: c#

Пишу программу с опросом пула модемов (они на COM - портах)
перебор портов осуществляется в бесконечном цикле

```
 do
 {
 ....
 }
 while(true)
```

Чтобы этот цикл не вешал UI программы, он "крутится" под управлением `BackgroundWorker`. Информация о портах(занят он или свободен) выводится "наружу" в виде событий. Так же в виде событий тот или иной порт "занимается" или "освобождается".
Все работает отлично, за исключением одного момента: Однажды запустив `BackgroundWorker`, я уже не могу его остановить. Стандартная процедура с `bw.CancelAsync();` тут не работает, поскольку внутри крутится бесконечный цикл.

Может кто-то подскажет, как мне поступить?

Comment: использовать [токен отмены](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/816785/179763)

Answer (score 0):

Отмена операции должна быть кооперативной => в вашем бесконечном цикле нужно время от времени производить опрос `BackgroundWorker.CancellationPending` и вываливаться в случае отмены операции.

Answer (score 0):

Приведу пример из старого проекта

```
_backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker { WorkerSupportsCancellation = true };

_backgroundWorker.DoWork += (s, a) =>
{
  while (true)
  {
    RefreshTemperature();
    if (_backgroundWorker.CancellationPending)
       break;

    Thread.Sleep(30000);
  }
};


_backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Это все в одном месте.

И когда нам нужно остановить выполнение используем `_backgroundWorker.CancelAsync();`