# Дождаться выполнения Thread (запустить его синхронно)

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Пока решил задачу так.

```
public static async void Potok(int n)
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        H[n] = new Thread(() =>
        {
            //вычисления
        });
        H[n].Start();
        while (true) 
        { 
            if (!H[n].IsAlive) break; 
            Thread.Sleep(200);
        }
        //продолжаем выполнение метода
    });
}
```

Может есть белее элегантное решение? 
В java например можно ".Run" использовать вместо ".Start" вроде.

Thread тут будет завершаться через ".Abort()" из параллельной процедуруры.

Comment: `H[n].Join();`?

Comment: Только непонятно, для чего тут вообще нужен новый поток

Comment: Зачем в таске порождать поток, если сама по себе таска берет (если требуется)поток из пула потоков.

Comment: @tym32167,@Bulson Thread нужен, чтоб его можно было завершить через ".Abort()" из параллельной процедуры.

Comment: Смотрю используется индекс `H[n]`, может проще задействовать Parallel.For()

Comment: `Abort()` - плохая идея. Создайте тогда класс вокера с флагом отметы, который потом будете дергать, когда нужно отменить выполнение.

Comment: для отмены выполнения есть [CancellationToken](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/816785/179763), вам не надо для этого городить новый поток

Comment: `Task.ContinueWitch` и туда код который должен дождаться окончания процесса.

Comment: И в Task создавать Thread это экстремально :) вот наоборот - можно.

Comment: Вообще не понимаю, зачем в наше время использовать потоки. В 99% достаточно простого async/await. Я не вижу в вашей задаче чего то такого, что требовало бы потоки. Так может вам отказаться от него?