# Ожидание окончания потока при закрытии приложения

Tags: c#, winforms, многопоточность

Запускаю поток, в котором есть цикл while(true). В цикле есть

```
while (form.trigger == "pause")
{
    if (form.trigger_status == "start")
    {
        Action action_trigger = () => form.textBox1.Text = "Поток приостановлен \r\n" + form.textBox1.Text;
        form.textBox1.Invoke(action_trigger);
        form.trigger_status = "pause";
    }
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

В цикле парсится информация. Очень важно, чтобы парсинг не повторялся. В БД я уже всё расставил и обозначил контрольные точки для запуска и остановки парсинга. Но, когда я закрываю приложение, само собой, в БД может не записаться информация, которая очень важна для меня. Поэтому, нажав на свойства формы в конструкторе форм, я создал в событиях FormClosing функцию close_app. В нём я написал следующее:

```
Form1 form = Application.OpenForms["Form1"] as Form1;
form.trigger = "pause";
while (form.trigger_status == "start")
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
form.myThread.Abort();
form.myThread.Join();
```

Но, почему-то в потоке не доходит до

```
while (form.trigger == "pause")
```

Соответственно, не меняется triger_status и не закрывается приложение. В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: [CancellationToken для чего?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/816785/179763)

Comment: @tym32167 почитал. Не подходит

Comment: почитайте ещё раз или поясните, что именно не подходит

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вместо вот этих строчек:

```
while (form.trigger_status == "start")
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
form.myThread.Abort();
form.myThread.Join();
```

напишите следующее:

```
while (form.myThread.IsAlive)
{
    Application.DoEvents();
}
```

таким образом мы дожидаемся завершения потока, не блокируя при этом UI (за это отвечает `Application.DoEvents`). Помимо этого, советую полю `trigger` выставить модификатор `volatile` – так следует делать для всех полей, к которым обращаются несколько потоков одновременно.

А вообще, советую посмотреть в сторону асинхронного программирования с помощью async/await.

Answer (score 2):

Проблема в том, что

```
while (form.trigger_status == "start")
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

блокирует цикл обработки сообщений, так что вызов form.textBox1.Invoke будет вечно ожидать выполнения делегата. Кроме того, проверка свойств в цикле (тем более, строковых) - по меньшей мере, не самый лучший способ синхронизации потоков.

Как сделать это правильно? Логичным решением было бы вместо потоков использовать асинхронные задачи и await. Но можно применить и классический способ с EventWaitHandle и MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern int MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx(uint nCount, IntPtr[] pHandles,
           uint dwMilliseconds, uint dwWakeMask, uint dwFlags);

        const uint QS_ALLEVENTS = 1215;
        const int WAIT_OBJECT_0 = 0;
        const int WAIT_FAILED = -1;
        const uint INFINITE = 0xFFFFFFFF;

        //ожидает событие с обработкой сообщений
        public static void WaitEvent(EventWaitHandle evt)
        {    
            var swh = evt.SafeWaitHandle;

            using (swh)
            {
                IntPtr h = swh.DangerousGetHandle();

                while (true)
                {
                    int res = MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx(1, new IntPtr[] { h }, INFINITE, QS_ALLEVENTS, 0);
                    switch (res)
                    {
                        case WAIT_OBJECT_0:
                            return;
                        case WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 1:
                            Application.DoEvents();
                            break;
                        default:
                            throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();            
        }

        EventWaitHandle evt; //объект для синхронизации

        void DoWork()
        {
            evt = new ManualResetEvent(false);

            try
            {
                //выполняем операции...
            }
            finally
            {
                evt.Set(); //сигнализируем об окончании обработки
            }
        }        

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Thread th;
            th = new Thread(DoWork);
            th.Start(); //запускаем обработку в фоновом потоке            
        }     

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (evt != null)
            {
                WaitEvent(evt); //ожидаем конца фоновой обработки
            }
        }
    }  
}
```