# Как остановить поток по нажатию клавиши C#

Tags: c#, многопоточность

есть поток, который будет эмулировать клики мыши, так же между нажатиями мыши будут происходить заморозки этого потока(Thread.Sleep()). Есть идеи как можно останавливать поток по нажатию какой-либо кнопки, к примеру Escape

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Thread myThread = new Thread(Thr);
        myThread.Start();
    }


    private static void Thr()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(300);
            Click(323, 454);
        }
    }
```

Comment: так у вас просблема определить. что кнопка нажата или проблема с тем, чтобы поток остановить? Ну и где ваш код, с которым работаете?

Comment: скорее в кнопке. Код добавил

Comment: а вообще, мне нужно событие которое будет срабатывает на нажатие клавиши, даже когда окно свернуто или не активно(win forms)

Comment: есть методы Abort и Interrupt только Abort -  тогда, когда это становится возможно

Comment: 1) Видимо, вам нужен хук на клавиатуру 2) У вас нет вызода из потока 3) Если создаете поток, указывайте, что это background поток, иначе ваш процесс не сможет завершиться, пока поток работает 4) из фонового потока у вас нет доступа к UI элементам, что вы делать в `Click` собрались? 5) Почему поток у вас как локальная переменная, а не поле формы? 6) Если уж запусааете поток, который что то может делать с формой, то запускайте его когда форма загрузилась,  а не в конструкторе формы.

Comment: 5ое потому что этот код показан как пример, он никак не реализован. 4ое, вызывать метод клика из user32.dll.
И, да) походу хуки это то что мне надо, спасибо)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Коротко о моём костыльном коде, инициализируется хук на эскейп в загрузке формы, далее при первом нажатии хука создаётся CancellationToken, и запускается Task который делает клики, при втором нажатии эскейп проверяется существует ли токен и есть ли у него запрос на отмену, и если условие истина, то он закрывает токен, а тот второй поток.
Более чем уверен что я что-то да написал не правильно, буду рад замечаниям

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace AutoBrute
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        CancellationTokenSource cancelTokenSource;
        static CancellationToken token;
        private Hook _hook;



        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, uint dwFlags, UIntPtr dwExtraInfo);


        [DllImport("user32.dll")]//загружает метод для клика из win api
        public static extern long mouse_event(int dsFlags, int dx, int dy, int cByttons, int dsExtraInfo);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]//перемещает указатель мыши
        public static extern long SetCursorPos(int x, int y);


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            //установка глобальных хуков клавиатуры
            keybd_event(0x90, 0x45, 0x1, (UIntPtr)0);

            _hook = new Hook(27); //Передаем код клавиши на которую ставим хук, тут это Escape
            _hook.KeyPressed += new KeyPressEventHandler(_hook_KeyPressedEscape);
            _hook.SetHook();


        }



        void _hook_KeyPressedEscape(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e) //Событие нажатия клавиши Escape
        {
            if(cancelTokenSource?.IsCancellationRequested==false)
            {

                cancelTokenSource.Cancel();
                cancelTokenSource = null;
            }
            else
            {
                //токены для остановки потока который будет кликать
                cancelTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
                token = cancelTokenSource.Token;

                Task a = new Task(Clicks);
                a.Start();
            }        }


        private void Clicks()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    return;
                }

                Random r = new Random();
                int WidthMax = 1280;
                int HeightMax = 1024;


                mouse_event(2, r.Next(WidthMax), r.Next(HeightMax),0,0);
                mouse_event(4, r.Next(WidthMax), r.Next(HeightMax),0,0);

                Thread.Sleep(400);
            }
        }





    }
}
```

Ну и сам класс для работы с хуками

```
 public class Hook : IDisposable
    {
        #region Declare WinAPI functions
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lpFileName);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, KeyboardHookProc callback, IntPtr hInstance, uint threadId);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr idHook, int nCode, int wParam, IntPtr lParam);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hInstance);
        #endregion
        #region Constants
        private const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;
        private const int WH_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
        #endregion

        // код клавиши на которую ставим хук
        public int _key;
        public event KeyPressEventHandler KeyPressed;

        private delegate IntPtr KeyboardHookProc(int code, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
        private KeyboardHookProc _proc;
        private IntPtr _hHook = IntPtr.Zero;

        public Hook(int keyCode)
        {
            _key = keyCode;
            _proc = HookProc;
        }

        public void SetHook()
        {
            var hInstance = LoadLibrary("User32");
            _hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, _proc, hInstance, 0);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            UnHook();
        }

        public void UnHook()
        {
            UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hHook);
        }

        private IntPtr HookProc(int code, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
        {
            if ((code >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr)WH_KEYDOWN) && Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam) == _key)
            {

                // бросаем событие
                if (KeyPressed != null)
                {
                    KeyPressed(this, new KeyPressEventArgs(Convert.ToChar(code)));
                }
            }

            // пробрасываем хук дальше
            return CallNextHookEx(_hHook, code, (int)wParam, lParam);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Для получения нажатых клавиш используйте [Keyboard hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604410/global-keyboard-capture-in-c-sharp-application).

Далее, чтобы завершить поток после того, как поймали нужную клавишу, можно использовать просто bool переменную, которая будет использована в вашем while цикле, выглядеть это будет примерно так:

```
bool cancelThread = false;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Thread myThread = new Thread(Thr);
    myThread.Start();
}


void Thr()
{
    while (!cancelThread)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(300);
        Click(323, 454);
    }
}
```

В событии пойманной клавиши присвойте переменной cancelThread значение true и цикл будет завершен, а вместе с ним и поток.

Но мой вам совет, прочитайте про [async/await](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/)

Comment: `чтобы завершить поток после того, как поймали нужную клавишу, можно использовать просто bool переменную` - [CancellationToken для чего?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/816785/179763)

Comment: Ознакомьтесь: [volatile](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/volatile).

Comment: Хоспаде, я же в конце ответа написал про async и await, само собой, что CancellationToken использовать куда разумнее, но я подвёл ответ под вопрос.