# Изменение статуса потока

Tags: c#, .net

Подскажите пожалуйста. Создаю новый поток Thread и запускаю его, затем я проверяю его состояние IsActive, мне нужно когда оно будет равно false снова запустить поток. При запуске IsActive изменяется на true, а вот как обратно изменить на false?

Comment: может `IsAlive`?

Comment: Поток нельзя перезапустить

Comment: [CancellationToken для чего?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/816785/179763)

Comment: Высока вероятность, что вы хотите что-то сделать не так, как желательно. Опишите чуть подробней вашу задачу.

Answer (score 0):

Для этого тред должен завершиться выполнив всю работу либо необходимо вызвать метод Abort
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.abort?view=netframework-4.8