# Отменить/Завершить Task

Tags: c#, tpl

Нужно по кнопке отменить или завершить выполнение операции, не пойму, как сделать это при нажатии кнопки. Код прилагаю

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace FTPDownload
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    Task task;


    private void btnDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //task = new Task(() => Download());
        //task.Start();

        Task.Run(() => Download());
        //придумать, как убить таск
        //придумать, как убить таск
    }
    private void Download()
    {
        try
        {
            string url = txtFTP.Text;
            string filename = txtSave.Text;

            FtpWebRequest sizeRequest =
(FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            sizeRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("anonymous", "anonymous");
            sizeRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.GetFileSize;

            int size = (int)sizeRequest.GetResponse().ContentLength;

            progressBar1.Invoke(
                (MethodInvoker)(() => progressBar1.Maximum = size));


            FtpWebRequest request =
                (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential();
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;

            using (Stream ftpStream = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
            using (Stream fileStream = File.Create(filename))
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[10240];
                int read;
                while ((read = ftpStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                    int position = (int)fileStream.Position;
                    progressBar1.Invoke(
                        (MethodInvoker)(() => progressBar1.Value = position));
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        }
    }

    private void btnAbort_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
    }

    //private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    //{
    //    var url = txtFTP.Text;
    //    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    //    webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(webClient_DownloadProgressChanged);
    //    webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(webClient_DownloadFileCompleted);
    //    webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(url), @"D:\cXPBootstrap.jar");
    //}

    //private void webClient_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    //{
    //    MessageBox.Show("Done!");
    //}

    //private void webClient_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    //{
    //    progressBar1.Maximum = (int)e.TotalBytesToReceive / 100;
    //    progressBar1.Value = (int)e.BytesReceived / 100;
    //}


}
```

}

Comment: [CancellationToken для чего?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/816785/179763)

Comment: @tym32167 я гуглил, но так и не понял, во всяком случае уже придумал, как решить мою проблему.

Comment: Мне кажется вам все равно будет не лишним глянуть на ссылку, для общего развития.

Comment: [Cancellation in Managed Threads](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads). И смотрите другие ссылки в меню слева.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace FTPDownload
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        bool flag = false;

        private void btnDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Task.Run(() => Download());
        }
        private void Download()
        {
            try
            {
                string url = txtFTP.Text;
                string filename = txtSave.Text;

                FtpWebRequest sizeRequest =
    (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                sizeRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("anonymous", "anonymous");
                sizeRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.GetFileSize;

                int size = (int)sizeRequest.GetResponse().ContentLength;

                progressBar1.Invoke(
                    (MethodInvoker)(() => progressBar1.Maximum = size));


                FtpWebRequest request =
                    (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential();
                request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;

                using (Stream ftpStream = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
                using (Stream fileStream = File.Create(filename))
                {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[10240];
                    int read;
                    while ((read = ftpStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0 && !flag)
                    {
                        fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                        int position = (int)fileStream.Position;
                        progressBar1.Invoke(
                            (MethodInvoker)(() => progressBar1.Value = position));
                    }
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
            }
        }

        private void btnAbort_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            flag = true;
        }

      

    }
}
```

Comment: Без использования [volatile](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/volatile) на поле `bool flag` это может сломаться в любой момент.

Comment: И уберите ненужный (закомментированный) код.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Да если по-нормальному подходить, то и `volatile` недостаточно https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29411961/c-sharp-and-thread-safety-of-a-bool

Answer (score 0):

Используйте `CancellationTokenSource` и `CancellationToken`. Для этого создайте асинхронную версию вашего метода:

```
public Data DownloadData() { <...> }
public async Task<Data> DownloadDataAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) { <...> }
```

Встаёт логичный вопрос: «А как его использовать?» Очень просто! М-ду операциями вызываете `cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();` Когда будет вызван метод `CancellationTokenSource.Cancel()`, то `CancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested` становиться равным `true`. Дело в том, что `CancellationToken` – это всего лишь структура с 1-м полем – ссылкой на объект типа `CancellationTokenSource`. Метод `CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` вызовет исключение `OperationCanceledException`, которое вызовет моментальный выход из данного метода. Вот пример:

```
public void Main()
{
    using var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var ct = cts.Token;

    var task = DownloadAsync(ct);
    cts.CancelAfter(1000);
    
    try { task.Wait(); }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    { Console.WriteLine("Operation was canceled!"); }
}
public async Task<Data> DownloadAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

    // sending request
    // receiving response

    cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

    if (!response.IsSucceeded) { <...> }

    cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

    var resBody = Encoding.GetString(response.Data);

    cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

    return resBody;
}
```

---

Раньше для отмены использовалось прерывание потоков, но т. к. не все методы не являются ["чистыми"](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8) (т. е. могут иметь освобождаемые ресурсы, запросы на сервер, не закрытые дескрипторы (например, `FileStream`), блокировка без последующей разблокировки и т. д.), то прерывание может нарушить эти процессы. В итоге было принято решение перенести прерывание на исполняемый поток. В .NET это реализовано посредством исключений, как самого подходящего способа. Так же вы можете просто выходить из метода, не вызывая исключения, если отмена подразумевает, например, отмену бесконечного цикла.

Сами по себе отмены нужно использовать м-ду каждыми блоками законченого кода, т. е. м-ду блоками кода, после прерывания работы которых не произойдёт *никаких* [побочных эффектов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%8D%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)). Мой пример показателен, т. к. мы не используем отмену внутри блока с отправкой запроса и приёмом ответа, т. к. прерывание блока такого рода может нарушить работу как сервера, так и клиента. А блоки кода (которые было бы уместнее назвать строчками), которые являются "чистыми", после их отмены не несут какого-либо вреда.

Вы можете сперва написать синхронную версию метода, а затем его асинхронную (*или* параллельную) версию с отменами и (в 1-м случае) `await`'ами. Думаю, так вам будет проще.

Comment: я не стал тупо переписывать ваш код, т. к. у вас уже есть рабочая синхронная версия. проще понять принципы и применять их везде, вместо постоянного спрашивания на 1-у и туже тему