# Почему при Thread.Abort закрывается программа? Как остановить поток? C#

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Есть класс для инвертирования движения мыши. При вызове метода Stop программа продолжает работать. При применении Abort прога закрывается. Как остановить цикл в методе MouseLoop?

```
 class Inverter
    {
        private Point currentPosition;
        private bool exit;

        public void Start()
        {
            currentPosition = Cursor.Position;
            exit = false;
            (new Thread(new ThreadStart(MouseLoop))).Start();
        }

        public void Stop()
        {exit = true;}

        private void MouseLoop()
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground = true;
            Thread.CurrentThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest;
            while (!exit)
            {
                    Point newPosition = Cursor.Position;
                    int right = currentPosition.X - (newPosition.X - currentPosition.X);
                    int maxWidth = SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Width;
                    if (right >= maxWidth)
                    {
                        right -= 3;
                    }
                    else if (right <= 0)
                    {
                        right += 1;
                    }
                    int bottom = currentPosition.Y - (newPosition.Y - currentPosition.Y);
                    int maxHeight = SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Height;
                    if (bottom >= maxHeight)
                    {
                        bottom -= 3;
                    }
                    else if (bottom <= 0)
                    {
                        bottom += 1;
                    }
                    Cursor.Position = new Point(right, bottom);
                    currentPosition = Cursor.Position;
                    Thread.Sleep(1);
                  }}}}
```

Comment: А к чему вы применяет `abort` если у вашего потока нет переменной? Можете код показать с методом `abort`?

Comment: Есть подозрение, что вы дергаете Abort основного потока. Что и приводит к прерыванию вашей программы.

Еще один вопрос, какой у вас процессор. Если не Intel, ИМНИП,Вам нужно объявить exit как volatile, чтобы для всех потоков отдавалось актуальное значение.

Еще можно переписать код на CancellationTokenSource и передавать его как параметр в Start потока.

Comment: подскажите, как мне остановить функцию MouseLoop, чтобы инвертирование прекратилось

Comment: Ответ на ваш вопрос можно найти в вопросе [Остановка работы потока по нажатию кнопки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/758618/Остановка-работы-потока-по-нажатию-кнопки)

Comment: А где в вашем коде `Abort`?

Comment: А зачем вы вообще делаете этот MouseLoop-то?

Answer (score -1):

Я думаю, что лучше переписать это так. Не знаю, насколько это верно, но я делал так.

```
class Inverter
{
    private Point currentPosition;
    private bool exit;
    private Thread MouseLoopThread;

    public void Start()
    {
        currentPosition = Cursor.Position;
        exit = false;
        if (MouseLoopThread == null || MouseLoopThread.ThreadState == ThreadState.Stopped)
        {
            MouseLoopThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(MouseLoop));
            MouseLoopThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest;
        }
        if (MouseLoopThread.ThreadState == ThreadState.Unstarted)
            MouseLoopThread.Start();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        exit = true;
        MouseLoopThread.Join();
    }

    private void MouseLoop()
    {
        while (!exit)
        {
            Point newPosition = Cursor.Position;
            int right = currentPosition.X - (newPosition.X - currentPosition.X);
            int maxWidth = SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Width;
            if (right >= maxWidth)
            {
                right -= 3;
            }
            else if (right <= 0)
            {
                right += 1;
            }
            int bottom = currentPosition.Y - (newPosition.Y - currentPosition.Y);
            int maxHeight = SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Height;
            if (bottom >= maxHeight)
            {
                bottom -= 3;
            }
            else if (bottom <= 0)
            {
                bottom += 1;
            }
            Cursor.Position = new Point(right, bottom);
            currentPosition = Cursor.Position;
            Thread.Sleep(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: почему вы думаете. что ваш код лучше? Укажите пожалуйста его преимущества.

Comment: Ну, потому что я точно знаю, каким потоком я управляю, а также потому что не создаю кучу потоков при вызове Start(). В данном контексте я не считаю это нужным. Если есть варианты получше, я с радостью их выслушаю, ведь учится никогда не поздно.

Comment: я вас не осуждаю, по моему вопрос вообще дубликат, что я и указал в комментариях. То, что я написал вам - я это сделал только чтобы улучшить качество вашего ответа - раз привели код, укажите там (в ответе) хотя бы почему он будет лучше работать, чтобы читатели вашего ответа сразу видели ваш подход к решению проблемы, не парся глазами исходники.

Comment: Я это понимаю, просто я недавно начал отвечать на вопросы и получаются такие накладки :)

Comment: никаких проблем, спасибо за вклад в сообщество :)