# Сохранить все потоки в List и потом одновременно их всех закрыть. Как?

Tags: c#

Всем привет!Не получается сохранить все потоки в List<> и потом их все закрыть. У меня есть такой код:

```
List<Thread> threads = new List<Thread>();
int threadsCount = 0;
```

В threads я помещаю потоки.

```
Thread t = new Thread(foo);
t.Start();
threads.Add(t);
```

Но когда я пытаюсь пройтись в цикле и всех их закрыть:

```
for (int i = 0; i < threadsCount; i++)
{
   threads[i].Abort();
}
```

То у меня выбивает ошибку: Не удается применить индексирование через [] к выражению типа "int".
Помогите! Как правильно пройтись в цикле и одновременно их всех позакрывать???

Comment: трассировка стека какая у ошибки? Где конкретно ошибку выбивает? Зачем вам убивать потоки? Почему нельзя Task + CancellatonToken использовать?

Comment: @tym32167 Можно подробнее про Task + CancellatonToken? У меня в программе есть две кнопки. Старт и стоп. Старт запускает потоки, а стоп должна всех закрывать.

Comment: [Остановка работы потока по нажатию кнопки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/758618/179763)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Компилятор ругался и вы завели переменную `threadsCount`? :) Она не нужна.

```csharp
List<Thread> threads = new List<Thread>();
Thread t = new Thread(() => Thread.Sleep(10000));
t.Start();
threads.Add(t);
for (int i = 0; i < threads.Count; i++)
{
    threads[i].Abort();
}
```

Comment: Оператор < невозможно применить к операнду  типа "int" и "группа методов".

Comment: @Armadillo-CLD Вы уверены, что внимательно скопировали мой код?

Comment: Конечно. Как такой код можно не внимательно скопировать? И ошибка та не исчезла. Теперь их две: "оператор < невозможно применить к операнду типа int и группа методов" и "не удаётся применить индексирование через [] к выражению типа int".
Код
for (int i = 0; i < threads.Count; i++)
                {
                    threads[i].Abort();
                }

Comment: @Armadillo-CLD запускаю студию, чудеса какие-то.

Comment: Сам в шоке... Пишу на С++, а тут заказ, пришлось делать на C#, и вижу вот такое... Ужас. Может, нужно подключить что то?

Comment: @Armadillo-CLD обновил код, только что его проверил, работает.

Comment: Кстати, когда я пишу threads. то у меня не вылазят подсказки по "Count" и т.д. Есть только CompareTo, Equals, GetHashCode, GetType, GetTypeCode, ToString.

Comment: @Armadillo-CLD `List<Thread> threads` - это список, вы нигде не переопределяете? Может где-то локальная переменная с таким же именем?

Comment: Оу... Только что заметил int threads, вот я растяпа! Спасибо вам!

Comment: @Armadillo-CLD не за что. И лучше использовать `Task` вместо `Thread`. Особенно, если вам нужна производительность, создается или удаляется много потоков. Чем больше, тем `Task` выгоднее.

Comment: Можете помочь? Как реализовать точно такое же, но только с Task?

Comment: @Armadillo смотрите [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/758618/179763) пример с `CancellationToken`.

Comment: @Armadillo-CLD на абстрактном примере я вам практическим решением не помогу. Показывайте свой `foo`, и рассказывайте, что делает ваш код.